# Open Chrome Driver when the job is running via Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I'm trying to debug an error and found that the things are working properly in local and failing only in jenkins.
To find out the issue, i want to know how to open the chrome while the job is running in jenkins.

Im setting up the below configuration, to open the chrome driver in local.

```
<parameter name="browser" value="*chrome" />
<parameter name="runLocally" value="true" />
<parameter name="chromeDriverPath" value="/Users/sdmariappan/Downloads/chromedriver" />
```

After setting this up, the chrome app is opening up in local. Can some one help to get the chrome while the job is running in jenkins.

Comment: Place driver under project resource folder and provide the path of that project directory

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Jenkins where the host has been configured. If it is invoking on local that means the host has been configured as your local machine in Jenkins.

Please check the Selenium Grid setup and configure Hub and nodes setup to trigger Chrome on a different machine via Selenium grid.

**Official documentation:** https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use following driver manager dependency, so driver will run autonomous, without any hard coded path

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Usage is also very straight forward as shown below.

```
    //setup the chromedriver using WebDriverManager
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

    //Create driver object for Chrome
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    //Navigate to a URL
    driver.get("http://someURL.com");
```